# MySQL function that alerts if a new row is inserted

Tags: .net, mysql

Is there a function in MySQL that we can use in a client application that will automatically sends alerts every time a new row is inserted in a table?

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use/write a trigger, that will record the change in a specifically designed, just for this purpose, table, and a crone/what ever is used in MS environment to check this table every X seconds (you decide the X).
Or, write an extension to mysql...(Or pay one of the mysql developers to do it for you).

Comment: why not poll the table that is being inserted into?

Comment: Because doing things like this is the entire point of a trigger; usually, you want to use the tool designed specifically for the job.

Answer (score 1):

In some database (Interbase, Firebird, perhaps others...), your can trigger event.
http://www.firebirdsql.org/doc/whitepapers/events_paper.pdf

I ask one day in MySQL forums about this :
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?84,3629,3629

Answer (score 0):

The simplest but (arguably) the least elegant solution is to have your client simply poll the table for changes.